# How to understand the adverb word `declaratively ` in there?

Tags: meaning, adverbs

When I read the [document](https://www.airshipit.org/):

> Airship is a collection of loosely coupled but interoperable open source tools that declaratively automate cloud provisioning.

What's the meaning of `declaratively`? How to understand it in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is Kubernetes terminology. Understanding Kubernetes will help you understand `declaratively` because airship is leveraging on Kubernetes technology.

> Kubernetes (K8s) is an open-source system for automating deployment,
>   scaling, and management of containerized applications.
>   It groups containers that make up an application into logical units
>   for easy management and discovery. Kubernetes builds upon 15 years of
>   experience of running production workloads at Google, combined with
>   best-of-breed ideas and practices from the community.

K8s provides many resources by default and one can extend k8s functionality by adding [CustomResourceDefinitions](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-kubernetes-api/custom-resources/custom-resource-definitions/).

Airship is leveraging on K8s `CustomResourceDefinitions` to make its architecture declarative.